# how to get all objects of the same class in a list in R

Tags: r, list, lm

I have implemented a linear regression on multiple dataframes. 
Now I want to create a list that will contain all my objects of class `lm` to later use them for other analysis.

My `lm`objects are differentiated by groups according a name thus:

```
names(sortierfe)
[1] "bio1_lm"   "bio2_lm" "bio3_lm"   "chem1_lm" "chem2_lm" "chem3_lm" "pest1_lm"
[8] "pest2_lm" "pest3_lm"
```

I want to get 3 different list according to the names of the group like this:

```
bio.lm <- list(bio1_lm = bio1_lm, bio2_lm = bio2, bio3_lm = bio3=lm)
chem.lm <- list(chem1_lm = chem1_lm, chem2_lm = chem2_lm, chem3_lm = chem3_lm)
pest.lm <- list(pest1_lm = pest1_lm,pest2_lm = pest2_lm, pest3_lm = pest3_lm)
```

Since I have 60 `lm`objects this is a hard job to do manually, does any one know how can I optimize this?

Comment: Are you looking for `?mget`? E.g. `my1.lm <- lm(mpg~cyl, mtcars); my2.lm <- lm(mpg~cyl, mtcars); (my.lms <- mget(grep("my\\d+\\.lm", ls(), val=T)))`.

Comment: It’s unclear why these objects are all together in this list in the first place, if they don’t belong together. You can split them after the fact of course, but I don’t think this is a good idea — much better to keep them separate initially.

Comment: You can try `lst <- split(sortierfe, sub('\\d+\\_.*', '', sortierfe)); lapply(lst, mget)`

Comment: Not an answer to your question but maybe have a look at http://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/ for a possibly "tidier" approach.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to split, we can create a grouping index with `sub`.  On the `list` output, we can get the values with `mget`

```
lst <- split(sortierfe, sub('\\d+\\_.*', '', sortierfe))
lapply(lst, mget)
```